# MySQL one to many relationship in one query

Tags: mysql, one-to-many

How can I get data one to many relationship in **ONE** query?

Example: one book has many authors.

The result return should be like this:

```
array(
   'book_title' => 'HTML for Dummies',
   'book_desc'  => '...',
   'authors' => array(
       [0] => array(
           'name' => 'Someone',
           'dob'  => '...'
       ),
       [1] => array(
           'name' => 'Someone',
           'dob'  => '...'
       )
    )
)
```

I have tried using subquery to select the result but not luck:

```
SELECT *, (
    SELECT * 
    FROM authors
    WHERE book_id = b.id
) AS authors
FROM book b;
```

Mysql error "Operand should contain 1 column(s)" which means that I only can select one column.

You may suggest me using join but how it can archive the return result format like I have shown you?

Comment: there's a comma after the first `SELECT *`

Comment: are you hoping SQL will return nested tables from one query? If so, I think you are destined to be disappointed. A single query can only return a single flat table. However, you can join the tables, and then use PHP to process the results into the required array format

Comment: @ADyson Thanks for advice. i just trying look for better solution.

Comment: @EdwinWong I agree it is frustrating. SQL wasn't particularly designed with OO programming in mind. If you're interested in storing your data more inline with an object-oriented approach, you might want to consider a NoSQL type of database instead of MySQL, such as MongoDB or CouchDB.

Comment: How about the case if we want to do paginator on books, so is it possible to do it with 1 query?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
SELECT 
 B.id AS book_id, B.name AS book_name,
 A.name AS author_name ,A.ID AS author_id 
FROM book B
LEFT JOIN 
 author A ON B.id = A.book_id;
```

> Refer : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/633cfa1/2

Your output will be in numeric array.

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [bookId] => 1
            [bookName] => Book 1
            [authorId] => 1
            [authorName] => Author 1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [bookId] => 1
            [bookName] => Book 1
            [authorId] => 2
            [authorName] => Author 2
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [bookId] => 2
            [bookName] => Book 2
            [authorId] => 3
            [authorName] => Author 3
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [bookId] => 3
            [bookName] => Book 3
            [authorId] => 4
            [authorName] => Author 4
        )

)
```

Convert this  array to multidimensional array

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [bookId] => 1
            [bookName] => Book 1
            [authorName] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Author 1
                    [1] => Author 2
                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [bookId] => 2
            [bookName] => Book 2
            [authorName] => Array
                (
                    [2] => Author 3
                )

        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [bookId] => 3
            [bookName] => Book 3
            [authorName] => Array
                (
                    [3] => Author 4
                )

        )

)
```

> Refer : https://3v4l.org/q1dli

Comment: Thanks zakhefron! this is useful~ just need to make that PHP script into utility function so that can apply to all.

Comment: I had a case where I wanted to convert the answer back to array of objects, for anyone with a similar use case, you can always use `array_values()`.

Comment: @zakhefron How do you convert `numeric array` into `multi-dimensional array`. ? Any Idea?

Answer (score 4):

If you want to do it quick and simple, use [`GROUP_CONCAT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) with an appropriate delimiter character. Then split the resulting concatenated string field in your PHP application (or whatever language you're using) to quickly get the inner array you want.

This has the advantage that you will only have one row per book in the output.

Answer (score 1):

A Way that you want data might not be easy from mysql. Mysql will return as row wise. so Either books or author will repeat in result set. and you have to parse mysql result accordingly to prepare you array.

Try following:

1) All books with author as comma separated ids.

```
"SELECT B.*,group_concat(a.id) as authors 
 From book b inner join authors as a on b.author_id=a.id 
 group by b.id;"
```

2) All authors with book details:

```
"SELECT A.*,group_concat(B.id) as books 
 From book B inner join authors as A on B.author_id=A.id 
 group by A.id;"
```

Comment: Thanks Piyush~ the following query still need to run second query to run second query to get author info

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT b.*, a.*
FROM book b
INNER JOIN authors a ON (a.book_id = b.id);
```